# best lifecycle method to replace onLeave with

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In router v3, we used onLeave. In v4, the closest to onEnter seems to be componentWillMount.  However, componentWillUnmount does not seem to be as effective for me in relation to onLeave.

What is the best lifecyle method (or other practice) to use in place of onLeave?

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate API to use in place of onLeave is ***Prompt***

> Used to prompt the user before navigating away from a page. When your
>   application enters a state that should prevent the user from
>   navigating away (like a form is half-filled out), render a .

Here is the [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt) to official documentation

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I was thinking more in the vein of firing a function or messing with session (if one uses session), not a prompt or interacting with the user to make sure they did everything correctly.

`onEnter:  function doThis`
`onLeave:  function doThat`